# Read and display a binary image file in python

Tags: python, image-processing, binary

I am new to python,
I have a binary image file (unsigned 16-bit format and 512x512 pixel in size),but while using a python code I am getting error 
"ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

I am running the code as shown

```
import numpy as nmp
from matplotlib import pylab as pt

I = nmp.fromfile('raw.dat', dtype='int16', sep="")
I = I.reshape([512, 512])

pt.imshow(I)
pt.show(I)
```

can anybody please tell me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: You should post your full traceback.  Also the `sep` keyword isn't necessary for `numpy.fromfile` here...

Comment: Oh, I see your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pylab.show()` does not take an array as an argument.  It just shows what you've already plotted with `imshow`.

Comment: but using pylab.imshow(), i am getting this msg "<matplotlib.image.AxesImage at 0x8a97fd0>"

Comment: That's normal.  It returns a reference to the image axes.  It's just telling you that `imshow` returns an `AxesImage` object.  You can assign this to a variable like `axes = plt.imshow(arr)` and make changes to to how the image is formatted before displaying it with `show()`.  But that's more advanced and not something you need to worry about right now.  Try going through some examples in the Matplotlib gallery like http://matplotlib.org/examples/images_contours_and_fields/image_demo.html